# Third, right-floating div is below the middle one

Tags: css, multiple-columns

I'm going for three columns (I didn't want this originally but it looks best for my project). The right-hand one is insisting on staying below the middle one even while it floats on the right. What should I change?

The whole thing will actually be put inside another div, but that doesn't seem to be relevant. I've simplified the code down to the problematic area:

```
<style>

.contain {
border:1px solid;
width:639px;
height:500px;
}


.subAreaLeft{
float:left;
position:relative;
width:205px;
border:1px solid;
}

.subAreaMid{
margin: 0 auto;
position:relative;
width:205px;
border:1px solid;
}

.subAreaRight{
width:205px;
position:relative;
float:right;
border:1px solid;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>


<div class="contain">

<div class="subAreaLeft" id="contactInfo">
ONE
</div>

<div class="subAreaMid">
TWO
</div>

<div class="subAreaRight">
THREE
</div>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: you need to float the middle div as well

Comment: subAreaMid should have a `margin-left:207px;` and subAreaRight should have a `margin-left:415px;` or roughly those numbers that will push them to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for all three of the `div`s to float to the left, all three of the `div`s need `float: left` in the CSS.

Comment: For some reason, this is the only suggestion here that has fixed it for me. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, plut I feel like I've read somewhere that floating isn't cool any more, but I'll just stick with this (it's actually for a JavaScript project, the teacher just wants the page to look nice).

Comment: Floating IS cool, and used daily.  However, when you float and clear, use a clear-fix div (<div style="clear:both;"><\div>) or use the psuedo-selector ":after" and add clear:both, or you may have problems if your content extends below given height, or if your floats make more than 1 horizontal row.

Comment: Cameron: Could you clarify that comment? I know I implemented your suggestion incorrectly somehow, but I'm glad at least one of them works.I'll be taking a more advanced web dev course in the winter term, so I hope I'll get a better grasp of divs then.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>


<div class="contain">

<div class="subAreaLeft" id="contactInfo">
ONE
</div>



<div class="subAreaRight">
THREE
</div>

<div class="subAreaMid">
TWO
</div>

</div>

</body>
```

you just need to put middle DIV after the THird

http://jsfiddle.net/zJkHE/ check this

Comment: is that what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not to modify any CSS. Leave that alone.

Instead, move the `subAreaMid` div to directly after `subAreaRight` in the HTML.

```
<div class="subAreaLeft" id="contactInfo">
ONE
</div>]

<div class="subAreaRight">
THREE
</div>

<div class="subAreaMid">
TWO
</div>
```

This ensures that the `subAreaMid` div will not clear, and gives the desired result.

Comment: This will work, but some developers will prefer a CSS solution that leaves the divs in display order.